# Using HTTPS WSDL in Visual Studio/SSIS

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, ssis, wsdl

I've recently had an issue where I have a web service asmx file where clients can access the wsdl through an https address, such as https://example.address/webservice.asmx?wsdl. When adding a web reference to Visual Studio, it tries to access http://example.address/webservice.asmx?wsdl — which returns a 404 error as the server is not configured to allow non-secured access. This also occurs in SSIS when adding a web service reference, or web service task (even when a certificate is added).

In Visual Studio, I'm also able to add it as a service reference which generally works (except for double[] being changed to ArrayOfDouble, etc.), but it doesn't appear that service references are an option in the Visual Studio provided within SSIS.

I've searched around for this quite a bit and there seems to be no easy solution to force https to be used. Instead, I'm wondering if there is a way to import wsdl references into a project manually without adding it as a web reference (just to add the request methods). That way I can create my own https SoapClient that uses these methods without the web reference issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate client proxy classes by using the `wsdl.exe`

[Web Services Description Language Tool (Wsdl.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
wsdl /out:myProxyClass.cs https://example.address/webservice.asmx?wsdl
```

`wsdl.exe` can be used either by opening the `Developer Command Prompt`, or executing it from the folder it resides in: `ProgramFiles/Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\wsdl.exe`

Comment: Just tried it and it works fine. To avoid the https issue, I still had to manually download the webservice.asmx?wsdl file and save it as webservice.wsdl, then convert that wsdl to the proxy class.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate client proxy classes by using the **svcutil.exe**

```
svcutil.exe [/t:code] <metadataDocumentPath>* | <url>* | <epr>
```

[ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx)

The ***svcutil.exe*** is like a next generation of ***wsdl.exe*** utility. Svcutil allows you to generate proxies for both - web services and WCF services.
Svcutil supports DISCO protocol along with WS-Metadata Exchange protocol, which is an interopable standart of SOA.

In some cases both utilities wasn't generate client proxy, therefore you will need to do two things to get the WSDL you need:

1. Download all of the files that are referenced; these will be either `<?include>` directives or `<wsdl:import>` tags found within the other XMLs file, which pull in a second one. You need to check each new file, as there are often second and third level imports. Put everything into one folder.
2. Edit all of those include references to remove the URLs and just use local file references.

Once that's done, you can generate client proxy from local files by next command

```
svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /l:C#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the WSDL file by using disco.exe located in the same folder as wsdl.exe to download your web service wsdl file.

[Web Services Discovery Tool (Disco.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cy2a3ybs(v=vs.80).aspx)

```
disco http://www.proseware.com/prosewareWebservice.disco /o:"c:\folder"
```

And then you can go on and use Wsdl.exe to generate your proxy class

Comment: This is just expanding on @scheien answer and I know it was answered some time ago but I thought it would be useful for the community.